# why I can change Textview in my non-UI thread?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView  textview;
HandlerThread myThread = new HandlerThread("my");
Handler myHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    myThread.start();
    myHandler = new Handler(myThread.getLooper());
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"in act = " + Thread.currentThread().getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textview.setText("gzw " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String s = textview.getText().toString();
            textview.setText(s + "\n gzw2 " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }.start();
}
```

works fine in two run() method!why not get calledfromwrongthreadexception?
textview could be changed in two thread
first toast "in act=1"
textview is:
gzw 516my
gzw 517Thread-517

Comment: You know that's wrong.  How many phones have even tested that on.

Comment: but it really works fine in my phone. you can test it in your phone

Comment: it works in emulator too

Comment: It may work fine but desist from that.

Comment: Interesting question, which version of android are you running this on?

Comment: From above this comment seems to hold the answer: 
 
To my knowledge only the internal class ViewRootImpl contains such a check. Any UI code that doesn't touch ViewRootImpl will not throw an exception, but it is still not thread-safe. –  j__m Apr 10 '13 at 14:38

Comment: @JohanShogun yes!same question as you refered  when I add a button in my layout and change new Thread() into it's OnClickListener ,then I could get error "ndroid.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException"